# Is there an issue using Titanium.include() in 1.2.0 RC4?

Tags: php, tidesdk

Am I the only one having issues with the this?? I haven't got the exact code with me right now but it is something like the following... (this is the simplest of examples I am using to get up and running with TideSDK)

I have in my index.html...

```
<script>
    Titanium.include("testLibrary.php")
</script>
<script>
    var testresult = new testMethod();
    document.write(testresult);
</script>
```

And the testLibrary.php file that I have in my resources directory is as simple as...

```
<?php
    function testMethod()
    {
        $fixedResult = "The most basic php variable for display in the DOM";
        return $fixedResult;
    }
```

I have php switched on for packaging etc. It all worked fine when I included the php code within the index file so I know php is working, I just can't get include to work??

Comment: why are you calling new on the method? just try var testresult = testMethod();

Comment: also, you don't need <?php open tag in .php files

Answer (score 2):

Moving my comments to an answer, since not sure WikingFrog got notified via email re: comments

why are you calling new on the method? `var testresult = testMethod();` should work

also, you don't need `<?php` open tag in .php files which maybe the source of your issue.

Comment: Magic, thanks for the input. The 'new' came from following an example I found elsewhere, my bad. Will have a go without the php tags and see how I get on.